# How to avoid bind(this) in Angular directive controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

I have ES6 class for directive controller:

```
export default class LoginController {
    constructor($state, store, auth, principal) {
        this.$state = $state;
        this.store = store;
        this.auth = auth;
        this.principal = principal;
        this.loginFailed = false;
        this.loginErrorMessage = '';            
    }

    onLoginSuccess(profile, token) {            
        this.store.set('profile', profile);
        this.store.set('token', token);
        this.principal.updateCurrent(profile, token);

        this.$state.go('main');
    }

    onLoginFailed(error) {
        this.loading = false;
        this.loginFailed = true;
        this.loginErrorMessage = error.details.error_description;
    }   


    signGoogle() {
        this.signOAuth('google-oauth2');
    }    

    signOAuth(connection) {
        this.loading = true;
        this.auth.signin({
            popup: true,
            connection: connection,
            scope: 'openid name email'
        }, this.onLoginSuccess.bind(this), this.onLoginFailed.bind(this));
    }
}

LoginController.$inject = [
    '$state', 'localStorageService', 'auth', 'principal'
];
```

In the `signOAuth` method I have two callbacks: `onLoginSuccess` and `onLoginFailed`. To properly call them I have to use `bind(this)` otherwise I get `undefined` for `this` in calbacks.

Is it possible to avoid `bind`? Or, it's a normal approach to work with ES6 and angular 1?

Comment: did you try to use: `var self = this;` concept?

Comment: @MaximShoustin: honestly,  I don't like this approach

Comment: i think you should pass only `onLoginSuccess` instead of `this.onLoginSuccess.bind(this)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the binding to the constructor, if that helps (not really):

```
constructor($state, store, auth, principal) {
    this.$state = $state;
    this.store = store;
    this.auth = auth;
    this.principal = principal;
    this.loginFailed = false;
    this.loginErrorMessage = '';      
    this.onLoginSuccess = this.onLoginSuccess.bind(this);
    this.onLoginFailed  = this.onLoginFailed.bind(this);
}
```

..., add a level of indirection:

```
this.auth.signin({
    popup: true,
    connection: connection,
    scope: 'openid name email'
  },
  (profile, token) => this.onLoginSuccess(profile, token),
  (error)          => this.onLoginFailed(error)
)
```

..., or create class instance fields (which may require you to add additional plugins to your transpiler, as they aren't part of ES2015 AFAIK; for Babel, I think that `transform-class-properties` handles these):

```
onLoginSuccess = (profile, token) => {
    this.store.set('profile', profile);
    this.store.set('token', token);
    this.principal.updateCurrent(profile, token);

    this.$state.go('main');
}

onLoginFailed = error => {
    this.loading = false;
    this.loginFailed = true;
    this.loginErrorMessage = error.details.error_description;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer.